# Uniqueness of solution of an integral equation in $C_b ([0,\infty))$ space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, integral-equations

I already proved that the space $C_b ([0,\infty)) = \{ f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} | f $ is continuous and limited $ \} $ is a Banach space with the norm $\|f\| = \sup |f| $. Now I need to prove that $\forall g \in C_b ([0,\infty))$ there exists an unique $f \in C_b ([0,\infty))$ such that:

$$ f(t) = g(t) + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ f(s|\cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds, \forall t \in [0,\infty) $$

Here's my attempt:  I'll show that the map $(Tf)(t) = g(t) + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(s|\cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds $ takes the space $C_b([0,\infty))$ in itself and it's a contraction. For the second part, my teacher gave the hint for using a theorem that I already proved saying that it is sufficient to prove that there is an $n$ such that $T^n$ is a contraction.

$(i)$ Let $f \in C_b ([0,\infty))$, show that $(Tf) \in C_b ([0,\infty))$

Let $B = \sup |f| $

Since $g \in C_b([0,\infty)) $ and the sum of limited functions is limited, then it is sufficient to show $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(s| \cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds$ is limited:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(s| \cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{B}{1+s^2} ds = B \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+s²} ds = B \frac{\pi}{2}$

Then $(Tf) \in C_b([0,\infty))$.

$(ii)$ Prove $(Tf)$ is a contraction.

$d(Tf_1,Tf_2) = \| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f_1(s| \cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f_2(s| \cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds \| = \| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f_1(s| \cos t|) - f_2(s| \cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds \| $

But I'm not sure how to get the above to $ < \| f_1 - f_2 \|$ neither how to show $T^n$ is contraction for some $n$, which is probably easier.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The linear map is $(S f)(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{ f(s|\cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds$ and you want to show that for every $g$ there exists a unique $f$ such that $(I-S) f = g$. The hint is to look at $S^n$. For example $S^2 f (t)= \int_0^\infty \frac{ S f(s|\cos t|)}{1+s^2} ds=\int_0^\infty \frac{ 1}{1+s^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{ f(u|\cos s|\cos t||)}{1+u^2} du= ?$

Comment: $S^2 f = \frac{\pi}{2} S f$. Since $\frac{\pi}{2} < 1$, then $S^2 $ is a contraction, hence $S$ is a contraction?  (Edit: Actually $\frac{\pi}{2} > 1$, this is wrong)

Comment: Note that the constant function $h(t) = 1$ is a eigenfunction of $S$ with $Sh = \frac{\pi}{2} h$ hence $S^n h = (\pi/2)^n h$ and it is not a contraction, so I don't see what your teacher meant, and I think you or him made a mistake.

Comment: But the linear map he gave me the hint is $Sf(t) = g(t) + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(s | \cos t|)}{1+s²} ds$, not $Sf(t) =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(s | \cos t|)}{1+s²} ds$

Comment: It is an affine map, not a linear map, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences

Comment: I see, not a linear, an affine map. But since my goal is to apply Banach fixed point theorem, I can use any map $S:T \to T$ that is a contraction in a complete space $T$, doesn't need to be linear, right?

Comment: Let $S f(t)= \int_0^\infty \frac{f(s | \cos t |)}{1+s^2}ds$ and $T = I-S$ and $\tilde{S} f = S f + g$. You want to show there exists a unique $f$ such that $T f = g$ or $\tilde{S} f = f$. $\ T,S$ are linear maps while $\tilde{S}$ is an affine map. For applying the Banach fixed point theorem you need to show that $S$ (or $\tilde{S}$ it is the same) is a contraction, but we proved above it is not (since $S h = (\pi / 2) h$ where $h(t) = C$ is constant).